# What is the entry point/file/function of Meteor APP?

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I am recently studying Meteor which is absolutely convenient and powerful. But so far it is still not clear what is the entry point of a Meteor APP, in other words, which file/function will be executed first?

A simple example:

client/hello.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Welcome = ({name}) => (
    <div>
        Hello, {name}.
    </div>
);
```

client/routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'react-mounter';
import {Layout, Welcome} from './hello.jsx';

FlowRouter.route("/", {
  action() {
    mount(Layout,
      {content: (<Welcome name="My Shining Name" />)}
     );
  }
});
```

then I use command:

> meteor -p 12345

Then a webpage is launched! It looks pretty magic: where is the server running? how the webpage is generated? Most importantly, which piece of code will be executed first?

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 3):

Meteor bundles source client files and ships the bundle to the client. JS may be transpiled, and style sheets may be auto-prefixed during the process. At the end, the client executes the bundle.

A source client file refers to a file in a folder named *'client'*. Those source files are executed in an order described in this [document](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order), quoted as below.

> 1. HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
> 2. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
> 3. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
> 4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
> 5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

Given the list, it's critical to build yourself some preliminary knowledge about the [file structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure) of a Meteor application in that understanding, say, which file goes to where (client/serer) and which files are eagerly loaded is crucial to deciding how to structure an application.

Getting back to your application. The webpage you are presented is essentially the React component `Layout` containing another React component `Welcome`. They are  mounted by `react-mounter` onto a DOM node in a HTML template, which I believe in your example application is a file named 'client/index.html' or 'client/hello.html'. The aforementioned node is usually a `div` with a specified `id` attribute, or a DOM node created by `react-mount` at run time.

Speaking of the server side, Meteor runs a [value-added HTTP web server](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/webapp) for when you start a Meteor application, and you program the features you like to have with [Meteor APIs](http://docs.meteor.com/).

I hope the information above help you proceed with building applications with Meteor. Enjoy!

Comment: So this basically makes reading other people's code much harder. Bad news for developers who have to fix/enhance people's existing code.